# the Index file of Categories was inserted with the _Layout interface above?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Can anyone tell me why I created Cate controllers after adding razor view mvc, the Index file of Categories was inserted with the _Layout interface above?
When i put RenderBody() at the top the _Layout is inserted at the end ?

here is img code of Index(Categories), _Layouu

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Categories</h1>




public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sldNC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDYc6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51hVk.png)

Comment: Perhaps add some actual code to illustrate rather than just links to pictures which many will never visit/see - I likely won't for example click them and if they get deleted in the future your question ends up with a very low value for anyone.

Comment: Hi, also pls share what is your Patial view and view component in the _Layout.cshtml.